# Changing an existing cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, cross-platform, phonegap-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

Facing the following problem has stopped my project for more than three weeks, help me please.

I need to use [cordova-plugin-media](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media) plugin for playing sound in Android. But I need an important ability that this plugin has not. So, I tried to change this plugin, but when I change or even delete java files (AudioHandler.java, AudioPlayer.java, and FileHelper.java) my project still work as same as before. I had cleaned and rebuilt my solution and also cleared Cordova Cache but I could not see my changes in running project.

My question is, how should I change an existing plugin?

I try both Visual studio 2013 and 2015 and all of changes that I have done are in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-reference your plugin in the Manifest file. Most probably, the manifest is not recognizing the modifications.